# Increase the index by one in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a rather simple shell script with a rather basic problem.
I have multiple files that follow this convention:

```
TOTAL_summer_2003-06-01.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-07-01.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-07-02.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-07-03.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-07-04.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-08-01.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-08-02.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-08-03.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-08-04.nc
```

I hope the structure is clear, there is an increase in month and day. Now I would like to subtract the previous day from the following day by using `cdo`.
If I put it in single lines, it would look like this:

```
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-01.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-02.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-03.nc
```

I guess the pattern is clear. Of course this can be done by using a loop, which I tried this way:

```
for i in `seq 6 8`
    do
    for j in 0{1,2,3,4}     
        do
        cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-0${i}-${j+1}.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-0${i}-${j}.nc RAIN_summer_2003-0${i}-${j}.nc
    done
done
```

But this does not work since the `${j+1}`  does not do what I want. I need it to be one higher than the actual `j` value.

If the `echo` command is added to the script instead of `cdo sub` it returns the following:

```
TOTAL_summer_2003-06-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-01.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-06-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-02.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-06-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-03.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-06-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-04.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-07-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-07-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-01.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-07-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-07-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-02.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-07-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-07-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-03.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-07-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-07-04.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-04.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-08-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-01.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-08-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-02.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-08-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-03.nc
TOTAL_summer_2003-08-1.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-04.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-04.nc
```

So it just puts a constant `1` there instead of `02, 03, 04 etc.`.

So the question is, how to modify the script so that it just adds `+1` to `j` in each loop?

Comment: `${j+1}` is a parameter expansion and, since `j` is defined, just evaluates to 1. See the section in the bash man-page, which is titled _ARITHMETIC EVALUATION_, to see how to do integer arithmetic.

Comment: There's a decent summary of native `bash` arithmetic operators [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html). The BashFAQ Wiki is [always a good source](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double parens, eg: `$((j+1))`, though this will lose the leading `0`; if you know the days will always be 1-4 then you could hardcode the `0` in the filename (like you're currently doing for the month).

---

Assumptions:

- you'll eventually need to deal with months `10 / 11 / 12`, so you'll need a different solution that doesn't prepend the month with `0`
- we don't need to worry about `+1` day causing a rollover into the next month (eg, 31 May +1 day => 1 Jun); otherwise we need to consider some additional code to handle 'date math'

Instead of hardcoding 0's I'd probably opt for using `printf` to prepend a leading 0 for single digit months/days:

```
for i in {6..8}
do
    printf -v m "%02d" "${i}"

    for j in {1..4}                     # use {1..3} if no files exist for day #5
    do
        printf -v d1 "%02d" "${j}"
        printf -v d2 "%02d" $((j+1))

        echo cdo sub "TOTAL_summer_2003-${m}-${d2}.nc" "TOTAL_summer_2003-${m}-${d1}.nc" "RAIN_summer_2003-${m}-${d1}.nc"
    done
done
```

**NOTE:** once satisified with the output remove the `echo` to have the script execute the `cdo` call

This generates:

```
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-01.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-02.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-03.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-05.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-04.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-07-02.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-07-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-01.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-07-03.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-07-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-02.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-07-04.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-07-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-03.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-07-05.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-07-04.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-04.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-02.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-01.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-03.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-02.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-04.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-03.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-05.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-04.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-04.nc
```

Comment: Thank you so much markp-fuso, this is what I was looking for. The solution is more complicated than I expected, regarding the quite basic question...

Indeed, the days of the month do not stop at day four. In fact, every single day between June 1st and August 31st is considered. As mentioned by you, the script does not work for the transition between the months, but I did this manually, which is not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a bit overkill but you can loop through the filepaths and fill a bash array with them, using the date (converted to epoch time) as "index".
Then you loop though each "epoch time" defined in the bash array and check if the index of the previous day exists, in which case you run the `cbo` command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# function Ymd2s()
#     converts "year" "month" "day" (in UTC time) to "seconds since EPOCH"
#     example: Ymd2s 2003 06 01
#      output: 1054425600
Ymd2s() {
    local Y=$1 m=${2#0} d=${3#0} tm_year tm_yday
    local -a month_to_days=( _ 0 31 59 90 120 151 181 212 243 273 304 334 )
    echo "$((
        tm_year = Y - 1900,
        tm_yday = month_to_days[m] + d - 1 + ((m > 2 && (Y%4 == 0 && Y%100 != 0) || Y%400 == 0) ? 1 : 0),
        tm_yday*86400 + (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 - ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
    ))"
}

files=()

# FILL THE ARRAY USING EPOCH TIMES AS INDICES
for f in some/path/TOTAL_*.nc
do
    [[ ${f##*/} =~ ([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ]] || continue

    t=$(Ymd2s "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}")

    files[t]=$f
done

# LOOP THROUGH THE EPOCH TIMES (ARRAY INDICES)
for t1 in "${!files[@]}"
do
    (( t2 = t1 - 86400 ))
    [[ ${files[t2]:+1} ]] || continue

    f1=${files[t1]}
    f2=${files[t2]}

    echo cbo sub "$f1" "$f2" RAIN_"${f1##*TOTAL_}"
done
```

**remark:** Here I converted the dates manually, with some calculations, but you can surely use the `date` command instead (=> not portable and slower).

example output:

```
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-06-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-02.nc
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-03.nc
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-04.nc
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-07-02.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-07-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-02.nc
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-07-03.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-07-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-03.nc
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-07-04.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-07-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-07-04.nc
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-08-02.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-08-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-02.nc
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-08-03.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-08-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-03.nc
cbo sub some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-08-04.nc some/path/TOTAL_summer_2003-08-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-04.nc
```

Comment: Thanks, as you said, it is a bit of an overkiller, but I will keep it in mind for future similar tasks.

Answer (score 1):

> the days of the month do not stop at day four. In fact, every single day between June 1st and August 31st is considered.

You could use the `date` command to format a date. It also accepts relative date descriptions like `+ 1 day`. That said, you can setup start date and end date variables, then add one day to the start date in a loop until the end date is reached.

```bash
start='2003-06-01'; end='2003-08-31'
while next="$(date +%F -d "$start + 1 day")"; test "$start" != "$end"
do
  echo cdo sub "TOTAL_summer_$next.nc" "TOTAL_summer_$start.nc" "RAIN_summer_$start.nc"
  start="$next"
done
```

```
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-01.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-02.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-03.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-05.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-04.nc
:
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-28.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-27.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-27.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-29.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-28.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-28.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-30.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-29.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-29.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-31.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-30.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-30.nc
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the same technique while iterating over the files directly. Assuming that files `TOTAL_summer_2003-06-01.nc` through `TOTAL_summer_2003-08-30.nc` are present:

```bash
for file in TOTAL_summer*.nc
do
  day="${file%.nc}"; day="${day##*_}"; tom="$(date +%F -d "$day + 1 day")"
  echo cdo sub "TOTAL_summer_$tom.nc" "$file" "RAIN_summer_$day.nc"
done
```

```
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-01.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-01.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-02.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-02.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-03.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-03.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-06-05.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-06-04.nc RAIN_summer_2003-06-04.nc
:
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-28.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-27.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-27.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-29.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-28.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-28.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-30.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-29.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-29.nc
cdo sub TOTAL_summer_2003-08-31.nc TOTAL_summer_2003-08-30.nc RAIN_summer_2003-08-30.nc
```

Comment: thanks pmf, also a great and quite elegant solution!